# Prevent Page Reload When File Input Clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I appreciate anyone's response and suggestions. I have a react component that loads a form to edit a product. When the component is mounted, it will receive props from another function and I use these values within the prop as default value of the input fields in the form. I also have an input element that accepts uploading a file. When the file is selected, the component seems to be refreshing and setting other input fields to their default values. Here is my component:

```
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <div className="form-row">
      <div className="col-md-4 mt-md-2">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          name="name"
          placeholder="Name"
          defaultValue={product!.name}
          ref={register({
            required: true,
            pattern: /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/,
          })}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-4 mt-2 mt-md-2">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          name="qty"
          placeholder="Quantity"
          defaultValue={product!.qty}
          ref={register({ required: true, pattern: /^[0-9]+$/ })}
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div className="form-row">
      <div className="col-md-4 mt-2 mt-md-2">
        <div className="input-group">
          <div className="custom-file">
            <input
              type="file"
              className="custom-file-input"
              name="posImg"
              id="img"
              title="Add image to product if it is a menu item"
              onChange={handleImg}
            />
            <label
              className="custom-file-label"
              htmlFor="img"
              aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon02"
            >
              {fileLabelState}
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="d-flex justify-content-end mt-2">
      <button
        type="submit"
        className="btn zaad justify-content-end"
        title="Submit product edit"
      >
        Update
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

The issue is when I choose the file and click on select, all the other input fields are reset to their default values. Here is my handleImg function:

```
const handleImg = (e: any) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  setFileLabelState(e.target.files[0].name);
  setFile(file);
};
```

I have tried to work with the e.preventDefault(), but I have had no chance so far. Any suggestions on how I can go about this?

Thank you again.

EDIT:
I fixed the form handler and now here is my handleSubmit function:

```
const handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  let editedProd = new FormData();
  let isMenu: string = event.menuItemOption === "yes" ? "true" : "false";
  editedProd.append("name", event.name);
  editedProd.append("qty", event.qty);
  editedProd.append("img", file);};
```

Comment: Sometimes you may need to also `stopPropagation` on the event object.

Comment: What does  setFile(file); do?

Comment: @DrewReese I tried that before and I tried it again. The issue still persists

Comment: @mplungjan setFile(file) is just adding the uploaded file to the state of the component. I will later on send that to the back end

Comment: write your  `e.preventDefault()` in `handleSubmit` function, right now you wrote that in `handleImg`

Comment: Why do you even use e.preventDefault in the file change event? What do you not want the change does?

Comment: Also what are you passing to handleSubmit in `onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}` I would expect `onSubmit={handleSubmit}` without the (), the () will execute the handleSubmit when the form renders if I am not mistaken

Comment: @CodeBug that is correct! I fixed it and the issue is still there

Comment: @mplungjan I modified my code and pasted the handleSubmit function above as well

Comment: And this? `onSubmit={handleSubmit}`

Comment: you might need to handle the submit on the  `button` instead at the `form`

Comment: @Se0ng11 WHY? That is not recommended

Comment: @mplungjan that one as well

Comment: do you have other function that refresh the page? looking at the code, there seem to have no code that actually allow the page to refresh

Comment: @Se0ng11 not really! Also, I assume the error is not with submitting the form, because I never submit the form. When I click on the file input field and I choose a file, only then other input fields reset to default values

Answer (score 1):

```
const handleSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let editedProd = new FormData();
  let isMenu: string = event.menuItemOption === "yes" ? "true" : "false";
  editedProd.append("name", event.name);
  editedProd.append("qty", event.qty);
  editedProd.append("img", file);};
}
```

try this answer note here i change `(event: any)` to `event`. this is working code from my project